# Why I'm getting a 401 unauthorized working with JWT in Asp.Net CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to make a User Authentication in Asp.net CORE using JsonWebTokens(JWT).

When I run the login method in my app the token is correctly generated, but, when I try to go to a method restricted with `[Authorize]` attribute, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

> Bearer error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The signature is invalid\"

This is how I configured in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("asdwda1d8a4sd8w4das8d*w8d*asd@#");
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);

            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidAudience = "Audience",
                ValidIssuer= "Issuer",
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

And this is how I configured in the configure in `Startup`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

This is the token generation in the `LoginController`:

```
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("UserID", login.IdUsuario.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("asdwda1d8a4sd8w4das8d*w8d*asd@#")), 
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return Ok( new { token } );
```

And this is the class that I restricted, the same that is denying the access

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("Profile")]
public IActionResult Profile()
{
     string userID = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
     var resultado = _UsuarioServicio.Profile(int.Parse(userID));
     return Ok(resultado);
}
```

I'm testing this with postman and I've already added the corresponding header.

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: did you try add "Bearer" word in front of your token, in header?

Comment: @xray the error says that signature is invalid which means that token is coming to the server but it doesn't have valid signature. Here, the keys are not matching if you carefully look at the code.

Comment: What @PrateekKumarDalbehera I believe it goes in the right direction.
I believe he's speaking about : 
 SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890123456") 
which is different to what is in **configureservices**

Comment: Hey, Thanks for asking!

Comment: I've already put the same signature that I have in the startup y the controller but the error continue and yes add the word Bearer before the token on the test

Answer (score 0):

The `key` in your token does not match what you are setting in the configuration. They have to match perfectly.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer! I've already put the same signature that I have in the startup y the controller but the error continue

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting an answer. Change your signature algorithm to `Hmac256`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice! I've already did it, I also proceed to put HmacSha256 instead of HmacSha256Signature but tthe error continues

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same symmetric key while generating token & validating token. From the code you shared, while generating token, you are using the signing keys as "1234.." but while validating in startup.cs you are using "ab de..". That's why, it is complaining that signature is not valid as both the key don't match.

Also, please store the keys in a secured configuration file. If it is for a real time, please use asymmetric keys (public key & private key)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer! II've already put the same signature that I have in the startup y the controller but the error continue